# Push website manually to the WayBackMachine from archive.org

Tags: archive

Is there a way to upload or trigger a snapshot of the own website to the WayBackMachine from archive.org? I've checked the FAQ and the archive.org API, but can't find any way to trigger this with a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that if you can trigger a call to `http://web.archive.org/save/{{URL}}` it will unofficially force-save the page. This seems to be a bit of a hack rather than an official approach.

Comment: The "Save Page Now" form on https://web.archive.org/ uses this URL and [this](https://blog.archive.org/2017/01/25/see-something-save-something/) blogpost refers to bookmarklets that use it too. Its official.